# LLVM: get address space in getelementptr

Tags: c++, llvm-ir

I have following LLVM IR instruction:

`%ptrA = getelementptr float, float addrspace(1)* %A, i32 %id`

To get the `addrspace` value, do I use function call `getAddressSpace()` or `getPointerAddressSpace()` or `getAddrSpaceCast()`?

-------------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------

I get error as `class llvm::Instruction` has no member named `getAddressSpace`, when I am using `Inst -> getAddressSpace`.

What is wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use GEPInst->getAddressSpace()  http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html

Comment: @lazyCoder Please check the updated question.

Comment: You need to cast(if you are sure that instruction is of gep or you can try dyn_cast) the llvm::Instruction to llvm::GetElementPtrInst.